# How to resuse selenium test file in another selenium test

Tags: selenium

Is there way where I can use one selenium test file in another test file like an include directive or something?

I do not want to create duplicate files, there is only one change I have to make in an existing test file so I thought if there was a way to use an existing test file ?

Thanks for your reply, I am using Ruby

Comment: Which selenium product are you using? selenium-ide? selenium-rc?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what language you use for coding. In java to reuse another selenium test file we use the **import** directive. If you are using java I can show you a sample pseudocode.

What language are you using?